# Change Opacity of Bootstrap Button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I notice that I can change the opacity of a `<div>` in bootstrap with the class `bg-opacity-50`. However, as I tried to apply this class to a `<btn>`, it appears to me that this class does not work. I tried to invent `btn-opacity-50` and use it instead, and it does not work neither.

May I know whether there is a convenient class I can use for buttons in Bootstrap that I can change the opacity easily? If not, what should I do in that case?

Comment: Where in the BS4 docs is `bg-opacity-50`? BS5 I can find, but not BS4

Comment: @j08691 you maybe right, i was not particularly conscious about the difference of BS5 and BS4 as i apply the bootstrap tags. I am not expertly savvy with programming actually